# Disabling gvfs directory monitoring on specific share

Tags: 16.04, samba, gvfs

I discovered that almost 75% of the errors in my syslog are

`WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: Operation not supported by backend`

I don't need to be able to monitor changes on any of my samba shares, so I just want to disable it so it doesn't junk up my logs. What do I do?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm using 16.04.4 and my logs are flooded with this very warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was suffering from the same problem, did try changing GVFS enviroment variables and related dconf keys, but didn't get any good results, so decided to look at the source code. I found the next code in the daemon/gvfsbackendnetwork.c file:

```
g_warning ("Couldn't create directory monitor on %s. Error: %s\n",
                   uri, error ? error->message : "");
```

...which is producing the warning described in the question. Btw, there are 2 places in that file with same warning in Ubuntu GVFS sources, while in GNOME.org's git 1 of the entries is actually g_debug, not g_warning. I decided to change both g_warning calls in Ubuntu version to the g_debug just because that would be smallest patch to clean out the syslog of these noisy warnings.

To reproduce next steps, you have to enable source code repositories first. Then run described commands in the system Terminal (aka bash, sh):

```
# install build tools
sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts fakeroot
# install gvfs build dependencies
sudo apt-get build-dep gvfs

# create temporary directory for the source code and get it via apt
mkdir ~/src; cd ~/src
apt-get source gvfs

# at the moment I've got gvfs-1.28.2 @ Ubuntu 16.04, update the path if you've got another version
# check g_warning entries to be sure what we're editing:
cat ~/src/gvfs-1.28.2/daemon/gvfsbackendnetwork.c | grep g_warning
```

> g_warning ("Couldn't create directory monitor on %s. Error: %s",
>
> g_warning ("Couldn't create directory monitor on %s. Error: %s",

```
# replace g_warning to g_debug as described way above
sed --in-place "s/g_warning/g_debug/g" ~/src/gvfs-1.28.2/daemon/gvfsbackendnetwork.c

# go to the source directory root
cd ~/src/gvfs-1.28.2
# bump version, edit changelog if needed, then save the file
dch -i
```

That will look something like:

> gvfs (1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2ubuntu1) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium
>
> - Keep syslog clean of the non-disableable warnings by turning them
>     into a debug messages.
>
>   -- Habetdin  Fri, 21 Dec 2018 20:00:00 +0300

```
# finally, build the .deb packages
debuild -b -us -uc
# one level up from the source root - to the compiled .deb packages
cd ..
# install them all
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

As a last note, description of debuild parameters I've got with `man dpkg-buildpackage`:

> -b     Specifies  a binary-only build, no source files are to be built and/or distributed.
>
> -us    Do not sign the source package.
>
> -uc    Do not sign the .changes file.

This is little bit dirty way to solve the problem, but I didn't find suitable built-in solution, so for now this is the only way I found to practically clean out the syslog.